# I want to show images in plt but something confused

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to show the image like `ratio= [0.1,0.2,0.3]`, but the image only show the first columns

```
   ratio0  ratio1 ration3

 limit1 
 limit2
 limit3
 limit4


def show_images(self, limit,ratio):
    k = 0
    for idxr, r in enumerate(ratio):
        for idx, (img, target) in enumerate(self.trainloader):
            # print(k,idx)
            self.adjust_image(r)
            plt.subplot(1, len(ratio), idx + 1)
            img = img[0, :, :].numpy().squeeze()
            plt.imshow(img)
            plt.show()
            if idx == limit: break
```

Comment: Can you include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of understanding your question, but It may help: you should use `plt.show()` after calling `imshow` for **all** sub-plots (not after every single one):

```
for idxr, r in enumerate(ratio):
  for idx, (img, target) in enumerate(self.trainloader):
    # print(k,idx)
    self.adjust_image(r)
    plt.subplot(1, len(ratio), idx + 1)
    img = img[0, :, :].numpy().squeeze()
    plt.imshow(img)
    if idx == limit: break
  plt.show()
```